# Selecting a value to decode hex string in PDF

Tags: c#

While we have a hexadecimal string, how to convert the hex string as it matches the characters in CharacterMap table. I have tried splitting the hex string as consecutive two character codes and then get the decoded values using `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber`. But some times it goes wrong and in those cases the above logic fails converting the hex string as four character sub strings and decoding it produces good result.

For example:

In the case: hex string `<030402>` converted to substrings `03`,`04` and `02` and then decoding  the substrings produces correct result.

In the case: hex string `<0000>` converted as `00`,`00` and then decoding  the substrings  produces incorrect result. In this case converting the hex sting as a whole `0000` to hexadecimal produces correct result.

Could anyone help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you paste the code that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing some of your specific breaking examples with expected and actual results would help.  But it sounds like you may not be accounting for Unicode's variable encoding lengths.  Under UTF-8, the range of a character's first two bytes indicates the character's size:

- 00-9f : one byte
- c2-df : two bytes
- e0-ef : three bytes
- f0-f4 : four bytes